# How to split the image using Javascript + CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have the image like this:

[image]

I want to split it into six squares, and I can keep looping to display the animation.
Do you have any ideas to split the image by JS + CSS instead of using 6 separate image files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [an article from SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/07/20/javascript-sprite-animation-using-jquery/) on sprite animation using jQuery.

Answer (score 8):

Set it as a background image and manipule the background position.

Update: As seth mentioned, the technique is called CSS Sprites. Searching google for [animation with css sprites](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS339US340&q=animation+with+css+sprites&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) turns up some good results.

Comment: It's called CSS sprites.  here's a tutorial about it. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two techniques

- Use image as background
- Use CSS clip

[Here](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/streaker.html) is a good example of use of first technique.